# How to convert Maven War project to an EAR project in Openshift?

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, jboss, openshift

I have created an JEE application in Openshift using the JBOSS AS 7.1 cartridge a Maven project have been generated with the War deployment format.

I need to use EJBs into the application but the War format cannot hold EJB so I changed the from War to Ear, the problem is that when I deploy the Ear the application does not Work(404 Error when I access the home page).

Is there any simple solution in order to make this work?
Or Should I create two seperate projects(one EJB project and another JSF project) and a parent POM?

Comment: You need to create a Maven EAR project and add the WAR as dependency plus other required dependencies.

Comment: OpenShift or OpenShifts Maven is HORRID at handling EAR deployments, what worked in  OpenShift 3 is a no go by default in OpenShift 4

Comment: @JGlass thanks for your comment. A lot of time passed since I published this question at an era when Openshift was not a Kubernetes distribution but simply a PaaS cloud :-)
This question brings a lot of memories :-D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it is possible to package EJBs inside a WAR archive : [JEE6 Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipio.html#gippi), so I decided to stick with that.

Alternatively it is also possible to convert a project from WAR to EAR by using Maven's project composition ([useful link](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/core/MAVEN/real_app.htm)).